# After sending APK to other device, application crash

Tags: android, apk

I spend some time writting basic android apps, and I wanted to share it with my friends. I tried both APK Extractor and sending an APK file from project folder. In both cases after installation an app icon and title are visible, but app crashes in the second it is opened. I even tried to do it on my phone. It works perfectly when I'm openning it via Android Studio, but crashes after installation from APK. What can be the problem? Do I need to put some permission somewhere?

EDIT
I needed to build APK one more time. Now it's working, I'll leave it in case someone will have the same problem. Just go to Build>Build APK

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#ir-limitations

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks for the above link.

Answer (score 1):

Goto File -> Settings -> Build,Execution -> Instant Run and uncheck the "Enable Instant run ..." Option
[uncheck option and click apply button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dONqf.png)